# SPSS: search for repeated occurrences at previous time points

Tags: repeat, spss

I have a dataset as such:

```
Case #|DateA |Drug.1|Drug.2|Drug.3|DateB.1 |DateB.2  |DateB.3 |RcvdDrugXTimeA
------|------|------|------|------|--------|---------|--------|--
1     |DateA1|    X |    Y |    X |DateB1.1|DateB1.2 |DateB1.3| 0
2     |DateA2|    X |    Y |    X |DateB2.1|DateB2.2 |DateB2.3| 1
3     |DateA3|    Y |    Z |    X |DateB3.1|DateB3.2 |DateB3.3| 1
4     |DateA4|    Z |    Z |    Z |DateB4.1|DateB4.2 |DateB4.3| 0
```

Each case has many records of receiving drugs at different dates. My endpoint is receiving Drug X at `Time A`, where `Time` is calculated based on the difference between `DateA` and `DateB` for each receipt of a drug.

If a case receives Drug X at `Time A`, then I want to know if they also received Drug X at a previous date (to determine if them receiving Drug X at `Time A` is a new occurrence or a repeat occurrence).

For each case that received Drug X at least once during `Time A`, I have variable `RcvdDrugXTimeA = 1`.

If they did receive Drug X before `Time A`, then I want `RcvdPriorDrugX = 2`. If they did not, then I want `RcvdPriorDrugX = 1`. If they never received Drug X, then ideally `RcvdPriorDrugX = 0`.

In the example above, Case 1 received Drug X but not within `Time A`, whereas Cases 2 and 3 both received Drug X during `Time A`, thus `RcvdDrugXTimeA = 1` for these cases. Say that this occurred for both of them at `DateB.3`. The difference between these cases is that Case 2 also received Drug X previously, thus making the receipt of Drug X at `Time A` a repeat occurrence. On the other hand, Case 3 did not receive Drug X previously, thus making the receipt of Drug X at `Time A` a new occurrence for this case. I would like to create a function that looks back across the records for those cases where the criterion of receiving Drug X during `Time A` is met, and to produce an output to tell me if this has happened previously or if it's a new occurrence. I would like to exclude those cases where they never received Drug X at `Time A` in the output variable.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand what exactly you are looking for. Please try to clarify more. I think an example will help a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I will try to clarify:
A patient has many records of receiving drugs at different dates. My endpoint is receiving Drug X at Time A.

If a patient receives Drug X at Time A, then I want to know if they also received Drug X before (to determine if them receiving Drug X at Time A is a new occurrence or a repeat occurrence). For each patient that received Drug X at Time A, I have variable RcvdDrugXTimeA = 1.

If they did receive Drug X previously, then I want RcvdPriorDrugX = 2. If they did not, then I want RcvdPriorDrugX = 1. If they never received Drug X, then RcvdPriorDrugX = 0.

Comment: OK next step is to add this explanation as an edit to your post, and add a visible example to the data (arrange it so we can see a case that meets your condition, why it meets the condition, and the wanted result for that case)

Comment: Okay, sorry I'm not the best at explaining but I have tried to make it clearer in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely sure I understand what you're trying to do, so the following syntax covers the example you gave and reaches the wanted output you described. If the example (and my syntax) don't cover other possibilities or considerations you need to include in the process, please let me know.

first I recreate your example dataset:

```
data list list/Case#(f1) DateA Drug.1 Drug.2 Drug.3 DateB.1 DateB.2  DateB.3 (7a10) RcvdDrugXTimeA(f1).
begin data
1     "DateA1"   "X"   "Y"   "X"   "DateB1.1"   "DateB1.2"   "DateB1.3"  0
2     "DateA2"   "X"   "Y"   "X"   "DateB2.1"   "DateB2.2"   "DateB2.3"  1
3     "DateA3"   "Y"   "Z"   "X"   "DateB3.1"   "DateB3.2"   "DateB3.3"  1
4     "DateA4"   "Z"   "Z"   "Z"   "DateB4.1"   "DateB4.2"   "DateB4.3"  0
end data.
```

Now I count the number of times drug X was administered, and then if RcvdDrugXTimeA is 0 the output is 0, if it is one the output is 1 if X was only administered once, or 2 if it was administered more than once:

```
count NofX=Drug.1 Drug.2 Drug.3("X").
compute RcvdPriorDrugX=RcvdDrugXTimeA + (NofX > 1).
```